# Generating a plantuml sequence diagram from a textfile description using iplantuml library

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plantuml

Hi does anybody knows how to read a text file and put it inside the @startuml and @enduml, the goal of this would be to make the printing of the sequence diagram more automatical inside a jupyter notebook

```
@startuml
read(~/Doc/trace.txt)
@enduml
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Probably have a look at the include statement.

Comment: this is what i tried but i still have an error 

file1.puml
\@startuml
C -> C : stuff3
D -> D : stuff4
\@enduml

inside the Jupyter notebook
%%plantuml

\@startuml
!include file1.puml
\@enduml

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d0628c067935> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('plantuml', '', '\n@startuml\n\n!include file1.puml\n@enduml')

...

Comment: I tried outside jupyter (don't have it) and looks like files are OK. Might be that  your plantuml version is old. Please don't place relevant information, i.e. source / error message, not in comment but edit your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and sorry for the bad indent of my comment, i will take notes for my future posts

Answer (score 0):

For me having the files:
main.pu

```
\@startuml
!include file1.puml
\@enduml
```

with file1.puml (with and without `@startuml` / `@enduml` doesn't make a difference:

```
C -> C : stuff3
D -> D : stuff4
```

and running:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar plantuml.jar main.pu
```

Results in:
[image]

I used version:

> PlantUML version 1.2020.17beta5

Comment: in my case i am trying to put it inside a jupyter notebook, but it doesn't want to work, so in my case i am not using the java usage, i am using the IPlantUML==0.1.1

Comment: See my comment with the question.